# YQL usage limitation - http 304

Tags: yql

Following a similar topic: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html , and after reading the YQL documentation regarding: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html, I still wonder about a certain issue:
considering YQL allows 1000 calls per IP, HTTP 304 (not modified) result still considered a hit?
meaning - are "304" results are counted as part of the 1000 calls per IP per hour?

thanks

**EDIT:**
I acceppted spier's answer since I got no better answer, and it;s been long enough since the question was asked :)

Comment: Did you want to link to another stackoverflow post with your first link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to indicate that cached 304 responses do not count against your limit.

http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the 304 responses counts to your hourly IP limit.

On the other hand if your underlying issue should be that the 1.000 calls are not enough:

What speaks against registering an application so that you get an access key and then use OAuth to authenticate? That would give you 10k calls per hour and 100k calls per day which is plenty for most use cases.